# Combining two vectors with rbind

Tags: r, vector, rbind

I am trying to make a column called `ID` that contains 5000 rows to act as an identification column for observations on 20 individuals. I want there to be 200 observations for each of the first 10 individuals, and 300 observations for the next ten individuals (because I don't want the same number of observations for each individual). So I made two separate columns:

```r
ID <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(12,122,242,329,595,130,145,245,654,878), each = 200))
ID2 <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(863,425,24,92,75,3,200,300,40,500), each = 300))
```

Why am I unable to stack one on top of the other (making a single column with all individuals) using `rbind`?

```r
ID <- rbind(c(ID,ID2))
```

Comment: You are looking for `data.frame(new = c(unlist(ID), unlist(ID2)))` or just `rbind(ID, ID2)`

Comment: data.frame(new = c(unlist(ID), unlist(ID2))) worked. However, rbind(ID, ID2) gives this error: `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names`.

Comment: In your example, the `ID` column name is the same, if not, you may have to change it to a common column name for `rbind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were almost there, just don't use c() inside the rbind

```
ID <- rbind(ID,ID2)
```

Comment: Sorry this is the error: `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names`

Comment: @Ryan This solution works for me. Is the example above the actual code you are running, or is it only for the sake of example?

Comment: I understand why it wasn't working it had to do with the naming convention I used in the code, once I ran it all from scratch it did work.